# How to use mapper attachment plugin with JAVA API in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I had executed basic program of indexing and searching with JAVA API in elasticsearch.
Now I want to index the doc, pdf, pptx file for that purpose I need to include Mapper Attachment plugin. For using mapper Attachment plugin with JAVA API I am looking for tutorial or sample program.
Thank you for contribution.

Comment: more explanation is here https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/92

Comment: Mapper attachment i had done with curl command now I am looking to implement it with JAVA API as a JAVA program

Comment: @Lav - Were u able to identify how to use mapper attachment using Java API. Any reference towards tutorial or example will be beneficial. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just add mapper jar to your classpath and when you will start a node, it will be picked up.

Have a look at what we did in [scrutmydocs](http://www.scrutmydocs.org/) project. It's somehow what you are trying to do.

Comment: the project is big and any other material for reference will be helpful .